# Как объединить скролы двух listview, чтобы работали как одно целое (.NET WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image: C# WPF]

- необходимо объединить sroll (размеры listview items одинаковые)

Comment: А почему не использовать несколько столбцов в одном ListBox?

Answer (score 3):

У меня работает вот так:

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="LV1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" .../>
<ListView Name="LV2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" .../>
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // вызываем, когда элементы загружены, потому что мы будем искать
    // в визуальном дереве
    Loaded += (o, args) => BindListViews(LV1, LV2);
}

void BindListViews(ListView v1, ListView v2)
{
    var sv1 = GetChildrenOfType<ScrollViewer>(v1).Single();
    var sv2 = GetChildrenOfType<ScrollViewer>(v2).Single();

    bool working = false; // нужен для избегания рекурсии
    sv1.ScrollChanged += (o, args) => Synchronize(sv1, sv2, ref working);
    sv2.ScrollChanged += (o, args) => Synchronize(sv2, sv1, ref working);
}

static void Synchronize(ScrollViewer from, ScrollViewer to, ref bool working)
{
    if (working) return; // избегаем рекурсии
    try
    {
        working = true;
        // вычисляем долю, на которую мы ушли вниз
        var kv = from.ViewportHeight >= from.ExtentHeight ? 0.0 :
                   from.ContentVerticalOffset / (from.ExtentHeight - from.ViewportHeight);
        if (to.ViewportHeight < to.ExtentHeight)
            to.ScrollToVerticalOffset(kv * (to.ExtentHeight - to.ViewportHeight));
    }
    finally
    {
        working = false;
    }
}
```

И нам понадобится вспомогательный метод:

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : DependencyObject
{
    T t = d as T;
    if (t != null)
    {
        yield return t;
    }
    else
    {
        var nChildren = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d);
        for (int i = 0; i < nChildren; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i);
            foreach (var c in GetChildrenOfType<T>(child))
                yield return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Спасибо + 1 
Спасибо + 1